# Create new models from an existing one

Tags: python, django, model

need some help with the next issue:

I got this model in Django:

```
   class myModel(models.Model):

       Name       = models.CharField(max_length=50)
       parameter1 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
       parameter2 = models.IntegerField(null=True)
       #
       #
       parametern = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

The "Name" field is limited to 5, and it gets data to update the rest of the fields, giving as result a main table with n entries which repeat name but have different parameters.

I want to create 2 table from this main one as follow:

The first table has to group up the data by names adding the values of each parameter. The result should be a table with 5 names and the total of each parameter.

The second table is the same, but giving the average for each parameter.

One solution may be to create and delete each table every time the main table its updated, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it.

Comment: Please don't create extra tables with aggregated data. Unless there is a serious bottleneck, a query will often suffice. In case it does not suffice, you can take a look at *materialized views*, for example in PostgreSQL.